# Походження слова "пусети"

Tags: етимологія, іменники

В ювелірних магазинах продаються різновид сережок - [пусети](https://www.zolotoyvek.ua/ua/brillianty/sergi/gvozdiki.html) (як на малюноку).

Ще можна зустріти назву такого різновиду прикраси - [сережки-гвоздити](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX7KmivYjfAhVLDCwKHdv4CUUQ_AUICSgA&biw=1366&bih=608&dpr=1).

[image]

Цікавить яке похрдження має слово "пусети". В словниках "пусети" не знайшла, лише слово ["сережка"](http://sum.in.ua/s/serezhka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/170482313) (в Україні зазвичай не відкривається через застосування економічних заходів проти компанії Mail.Ru; [кеш Google](//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://otvet.mail.ru/question/170482313)) пишуть, що в слов'янських мовах з'явилося від слова *pousette*, що має значення «шпилька з великою шляпкою», «кнопка».

Джерело, звісно, не викликає довіри, але наявність французького слова [**pousette** зі значенням «кнопка (для прикріплення паперу)»](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poussette#Noun_2) підтверджується, тому версія виглядає дуже правдоподібно.